# How to find a particular value from a string in C++

Tags: c++

I have this string "67030416680001337D4912601000000000000"

I want to take value before letter "D".
also want value 4 digits only after "D".

I have tried using:

```
string sPanNo = sTrkData.substr(0,17);
string sExpDate = sTrkData.substr(18, 4);
```

but problem is string before letter "D" will vary in length.

Comment: Iterate through the string and find it like that

Comment: `std::find_if(sPanNo.begin(), sPanNo.end(), [](char c) { return c == 'D'; };`

Comment: @Borgleader `std::find(sPanNo.begin(), sPanNo.end(), 'D');`

Comment: @Borgleader: Or `sPanNo.find('D')`, if you're not a proponent of excessively circumloquacious verbosity.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string::find_first_of()`, something like:

```
string::size_type dPos = sTrkData.find_first_of('D');
if (dPos != string::npos) {
    string sPanNo = sTrkData.substr(0, dPos);
    string sExpDate = sTrkData.substr(dPos + 1, 4);
}
```

Comment: @NeilKirk sure `find` will work too, just like `find_first_of` because it's more desciptive

Comment: `find_first_of` isn't needed here. You are probably not aware what it does.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use member function `find`

For example

```
std::string::size_type n = sTrkData.find( 'D' );

string sPanNo = sTrkData.substr( 0, n ); 

string sExpDate;

if ( n != std::string::npos )  sExpDate = sTrkData.substr( n + 1, 4 );
```

Answer (score 0):

or use `<regex>` C++ 11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

std::regex base_regex ( "(\\d+)D(\\d{4})\\d+" );
std::smatch base_match;

string numberstring = "67030416680001337D4912601000000000000";

if (std::regex_match(numberstring, base_match, base_regex))
{
    std::ssub_match base_sub_match = base_match[1];
    std::string number1 = base_sub_match.str();

    base_sub_match = base_match[2];
    std::string number2 = base_sub_match.str();

    cout << number1 << endl;
    cout << number2 << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to validate your input and extract the desired data in one step:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    string input("67030416680001337D4912601000000000000");
    regex re("(\\d+)D(\\d{4})\\d+");

    match_results<string::const_iterator> m;
    if (regex_match(input, m, re)) {
        cout << m[1].str() << endl;
        cout << m[2].str() << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "invalid input\n";
    }
}
```